# Multilingual instances show 'no such field' errors after update

Tags: upgrade, localisation, i18n, multilingual

I'm not sure if this is the forum where you want this issue raised, or whether Mattermost or a bug report is best, but here goes.  Please let me know if I should be raising this elsewhere.

A recurring error after updating a multilingual site is 'no such field' for a number of fields.  It is still occurring after the 5.2.2 update, in particular in the civicrm_uf_group view, where the following fields are missing:

- frontend_title
- submit_button_text
- cancel_button_text

Having got a bit fed up with errors like this occurring *every* update, it seemed, I have investigated further to discover the following:

1. It seems that line 375 in CRM/Upgrade/Form.php
   should read

CRM_Core_I18n_Schema::rebuildMultilingualSchema($this->locales, $rev, TRUE);
not
CRM_Core_I18n_Schema::rebuildMultilingualSchema($this->locales, $rev);

to tell the function that we are doing an upgrade.

2. When the schema structure is updated, a file of the form 
   SchemaStructure_x_y_z.php should be included in CRM/Core/18n, as SchemaStructure.php doesn't appear to be called during the update/upgrade process.  That file should contain the class 18n_SchemaStructure_x_y_z

The upgrade to 5.2.2 is giving 'no such field' errors because the latest schema structure file is Schematructure_4_7_alpha1.php, and so is the latest file to be called by the update process.

Is this a correct analysis, or have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 6):

In the latest version, you can also rebuild the multilingual schema yourself by navigating to API Explorer `http://www.site-name/civicrm/api#explorer`

Select Entity = `System`, Action = `rebuildmultilingualschema` and click on Execute button.

[image]

If you aren't able to access the API explorer UI, try using the cv command from the terminal.

```
cv api System.rebuildmultilingualschema
```

Or using drush -

```
drush cvapi System.rebuildmultilingualschema
```

Comment: Thanks, that is useful.  I'd read about it being possible, but it wasn't clear how one ran it.  But, shouldn't multilingual updates just work?

Comment: Agree multilingual should be handled during the update process. I use the above solution if it fails due to some unknown reason.

Comment: I found I could only get System -> rebuildmultilingualschema to work if I had first corrected the errors in the civicrm_uf_group view, so that is no solution to the upgrade issue.

Comment: Do you get any error while executing the above api OR the above page isn't loading for you? Can you paste any screenshot of the error in the description?

Comment: Basically, you just see System -> get and a rotating wheel waiting for the other actions to load after clicking on the down arrow that should bring up a list of actions

Comment: Updated the answer to use either `cv` or `drush`, if there is any problem on the API screen.

Comment: Presumably that only works in the Drupal environment under Linux? As aforesaid, multilingual upgrades should just work.

Comment: I think the way round this issue is that before you run the database upgrade process you compare …/CRM/Core/I18n/SchemaStructure.php with the last versioned example (SchemaStructure_x_y_z.php) and, if it is different create a new version (SchemaStructure_a_b_c.php) with class SchemaStructure_a_b_c if SchemaStructure.php is different.  I have tried this and it seems to solve the problem, so this could be an answer, but I should be grateful for comments.