# problems with upgrade on multilingual site (in this case 4.7.31 to 5.3.1)

Tags: drupal, upgrade, multilingual

When upgrading a multilingual site, after the database upgrade ran the site would not correctly load the status page (or any page that loads via javascript), for one example, the url used in the html calling the arrow image for the admin menu contains the string (for example) /en/civicrm/a/undefinedpackages/jquery/css/images/arrow.png or /es/civicrm/a/undefinedpackages/jquery/css/images/arrow.png

Answer (score 2):

There is some issue in rebuilding schema for multilingual instance when upgraded to 5.x version. For the moment you will need to manually rebuild the schema using drush or civi api.

Details to rebuild schema can be found at [Multilingual instances show 'no such field' errors after update](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25579/multilingual-instances-show-no-such-field-errors-after-update)

HTH

Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

this might be specific to this one site, but in case it's not here's what worked for me. after any upgrade to civicrm for a multilingual site, after the civicrm database upgrade, run

```
drush php-eval 'civicrm_initialize(); CRM_Core_I18n_Schema::rebuildMultilingualSchema(["en_US","es_MX"], NULL);'
```

replacing the language codes with whichever languages you are using

Comment: You can do it (marginally) more easily like this 

```
drush cvapi System.rebuildmultilingualschema
```