# Upgrade to 5.4.0 Fields Not Loading

Tags: drupal, upgrade

I'm on Drupal 7 CiviCRM 5.2.0. I've updated to 5.4.0 and received no errors. However, I started seeing that icons on the civimenu are not showing. When I lookup a contact, everything seems fine, but then my custom fields in each tabs are not showing (even though the count number is still there, e.g., Relationships 5). Very strange.

I also checked the Resource URLs, cleared caches and update paths, cleared Drupal cache, and nothing is working. Is there something I'm missing?

Tracking of All Errors

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
view?reset=1&cid=963:1 Refused to execute script from '[domain]/civicrm/contact/undefinedbower_components/jstree/dist/jstree.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
view?reset=1&cid=963:1 Refused to execute script from '[domain]/civicrm/contact/undefinedjs/jquery/jquery.crmAjaxTable.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

$Fatal Error Details = array(3) { ["message"]=> string(23) "DB Error: no such field" ["code"]=> NULL ["exception"]=> object(CiviCRM_API3_Exception)#231 (8) { ["extraParams":"CiviCRM_API3_Exception":private]=> array(6) { ["error_code"]=> string(13) "no such field" ["sql"]=> string(1093) "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.group_type as `group_type`, a.title as `title`, a.frontend_title as `frontend_title`, a.description as `description`, a.help_pre as `help_pre`, a.help_post as `help_post`, a.limit_listings_group_id as `limit_listings_group_id`, a.post_URL as `post_URL`, a.add_to_group_id as `add_to_group_id`, a.add_captcha as `add_captcha`, a.is_map as `is_map`, a.is_edit_link as `is_edit_link`, a.is_uf_link as `is_uf_link`, a.is_update_dupe as `is_update_dupe`, a.cancel_URL as `cancel_URL`, a.is_cms_user as `is_cms_user`, a.notify as `notify`, a.is_reserved as `is_reserved`, a.name as `name`, a.created_id as `created_id`, a.created_date as `created_date`, a.is_proximity_search as `is_proximity_search`, a.cancel_button_text as `cancel_button_text`, a.submit_button_text as `submit_button_text`, a.add_cancel_button as `add_cancel_button` FROM civicrm_uf_group a WHERE (a.name IN ("new_individual", "new_organization", "new_household")) AND (a.is_active = "1") LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'a.frontend_title' in 'field list']" ["tip"]=> string(62) "add debug=1 to your API call to have more info about the error" ["is_error"]=> int(1) ["error_message"]=> string(23) "DB Error: no such field" ["debug_information"]=> string(1093) "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.group_type as `group_type`, a.title as `title`, a.frontend_title as `frontend_title`, a.description as `description`, a.help_pre as `help_pre`, a.help_post as `help_post`, a.limit_listings_group_id as `limit_listings_group_id`, a.post_URL as `post_URL`, a.add_to_group_id as `add_to_group_id`, a.add_captcha as `add_captcha`, a.is_map as `is_map`, a.is_edit_link as `is_edit_link`, a.is_uf_link as `is_uf_link`, a.is_update_dupe as `is_update_dupe`, a.cancel_URL as `cancel_URL`, a.is_cms_user as `is_cms_user`, a.notify as `notify`, a.is_reserved as `is_reserved`, a.name as `name`, a.created_id as `created_id`, a.created_date as `created_date`, a.is_proximity_search as `is_proximity_search`, a.cancel_button_text as `cancel_button_text`, a.submit_button_text as `submit_button_text`, a.add_cancel_button as `add_cancel_button` FROM civicrm_uf_group a WHERE (a.name IN ("new_individual", "new_organization", "new_household")) AND (a.is_active = "1") LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'a.frontend_title' in 'field list']" } ["message":protected]=> string(23) "DB Error: no such field" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> int(0) ["file":protected]=> string(64) "/home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php" ["line":protected]=> int(45) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(10) { [0]=> array(4) { ["file"]=> string(77) "/home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php" ["line"]=> int(3340) ["function"]=> string(12) "civicrm_api3" ["args"]=> array(3) { [0]=> &string(8) "uf_group" [1]=> &string(3) "get" [2]=> &array(2) { ["name"]=> array(1) { ["IN"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(14) "new_individual" [1]=> string(16) "new_organization" [2]=> string(13) "new_household" } } ["is_active"]=> int(1) } } } [1]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(75) "/home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Resources.php" ["line"]=> int(689) ["function"]=> string(14) "getCreateLinks" ["class"]=> string(20) "CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup" ["type"]=> string(2) "::" ["args"]=> array(0) { } } [2]=> array(4) { ["function"]=> string(20) "outputLocalizationJS" ["class"]=> string(18) "CRM_Core_Resources" ["type"]=> string(2) "::" ["args"]=> array(0) { } } [3]=> array(4) { ["file"]=> string(72) "/home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php" ["line"]=> int(275) ["function"]=> string(14) "call_user_func" ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> &array(2) { [0]=> string(18) "CRM_Core_Resources" [1]=> string(20) "outputLocalizationJS" } } } [4]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(72) "/home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php" ["line"]=> int(84) ["function"]=> string(7) "runItem" ["class"]=> string(15) "CRM_Core_Invoke" ["type"]=> string(2) "::" ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> &array(12) { ["id"]=> string(3) "112" ["domain_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["path"]=> string(20) "civicrm/ajax/l10n-js" ["access_callback"]=> string(1) "1" ["access_arguments"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "access CiviCRM" } [1]=> string(3) "and" } ["page_callback"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(18) "CRM_Core_Resources" [1]=> string(20) "outputLocalizationJS" } ["breadcrumb"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["title"]=> string(7) "CiviCRM" ["url"]=> string(22) "/z/dev/civicrm?reset=1" } } ["is_ssl"]=> string(1) "0" ["weight"]=> string(1) "1" ["type"]=> string(1) "1" ["page_type"]=> string(1) "0" ["page_arguments"]=> bool(false) } } } [5]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(72) "/home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php" ["line"]=> int(52) ["function"]=> string(7) "_invoke" ["class"]=> string(15) "CRM_Core_Invoke" ["type"]=> string(2) "::" ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> &array(4) { [0]=> string(7) "civicrm" [1]=> string(4) "ajax" [2]=> string(7) "l10n-js" [3]=> string(5) "en_US" } } } [6]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(74) "/home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module" ["line"]=> int(445) ["function"]=> string(6) "invoke" ["class"]=> string(15) "CRM_Core_Invoke" ["type"]=> string(2) "::" ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> &array(4) { [0]=> string(7) "civicrm" [1]=> string(4) "ajax" [2]=> string(7) "l10n-js" [3]=> string(5) "en_US" } } } [7]=> array(2) { ["function"]=> string(14) "civicrm_invoke" ["args"]=> array(3) { [0]=> &string(4) "ajax" [1]=> &string(7) "l10n-js" [2]=> &string(5) "en_US" } } [8]=> array(4) { ["file"]=> string(44) "/home/jj/public_html/z/dev/includes/menu.inc" ["line"]=> int(527) ["function"]=> string(20) "call_user_func_array" ["args"]=> array(2) { [0]=> &string(14) "civicrm_invoke" [1]=> &array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "ajax" [1]=> string(7) "l10n-js" [2]=> string(5) "en_US" } } } [9]=> array(4) { ["file"]=> string(36) "/home/jj/public_html/z/dev/index.php" ["line"]=> int(21) ["function"]=> string(27) "menu_execute_active_handler" ["args"]=> array(0) { } } } ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL } }

$backTrace = #0 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(948): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE) #1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error)) #2 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error)) #3 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: no such field", -19, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.group_type as `group_type`...") #4 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-19, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.group_type as `group_type`...") #5 [internal function](): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -19, NULL, NULL, "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.group_type as `group_type`...", "DB_Error", TRUE) #6 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(224): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:8)) #7 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1907): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7)) #8 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1907): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -19, NULL, NULL, "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.group_type as `group_type`...", "DB_Error", TRUE) #9 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-19, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1054 ** Unknown column 'a.frontend_title' in 'field list'") #10 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError() #11 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.group_type as `group_type`...") #12 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2415): DB_common->query("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.group_type as `group_type`...") #13 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1607): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.group_type as `group_type`...") #14 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(438): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.group_type as `group_type`...") #15 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1394): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.group_type as `group_type`...", TRUE) #16 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/SelectQuery.php(143): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.group_type as `group_type`...") #17 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/utils.php(1254): Civi\API\SelectQuery->run() #18 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/UFGroup.php(75): _civicrm_api3_basic_get("CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup", (Array:3)) #19 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_uf_group_get((Array:3)) #20 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(169): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9)) #21 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(100): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:7)) #22 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(43): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("uf_group", "get", (Array:3)) #23 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php(3340): civicrm_api3("uf_group", "get", (Array:2)) #24 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Resources.php(689): CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup::getCreateLinks() #25 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Resources::outputLocalizationJS() #26 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(275): call_user_func((Array:2)) #27 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:12)) #28 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4)) #29 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(445): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4)) #30 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("ajax", "l10n-js", "en_US") #31 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:3)) #32 /home/jj/public_html/z/dev/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler() #33 {main
```

Comment: Strange. Did you clear the templates_c directory? And what about entering the url `http://yoursite/civicrm/clearcache?reset=1`?

Comment: Yes, I did both. Fields still not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved it by upgrading to 5.6.0, although it was a bit of a journey.
First I tried the solution in #6, but I found there were even more fields missing, having done a fresh installation of 5.5.3 and compared the columns in the civicrm_uf_group table: title, frontend_title, help_pre, help_post, cancel_button_text, submit_button_text

I was still getting the error, and the log table was showing that the error was on a view of this table `civicrm_uf_group_en_US`
So I assumed that now CiviCRM creates views of tables, which are not affected by changing table structure alone. Not sure if this is a new thing or if only for languages.  The site had been configured for only English US, but was selected as if it was a language.  Tried to change it to be language neutral. Not sure it made a difference.

Regardless, it seems that upgrading rebuilt the views, and problem solved.
Perhaps with hindsight I could have found a way just to modify the view without needing to upgrade.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 6):

Is the site configured for multi-lingual? If so then it might be an error with schema rebuild. Can you try rebuilding the schema using api explorer or drush?

Ref: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/25890/155

Or You will need to manually add the 'frontend_title' field to the table by running below sql query.

```
ALTER TABLE `civicrm_uf_group` ADD  `frontend_title` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Profile Form Public title';

ALTER TABLE `civicrm_uf_group` ADD  `add_cancel_button` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Should a Cancel button be included in this Profile form.';
```

Comment: No, it isn't configured as multi-lingual. I tried doing the solutions on that page just in case, but I see no changes.

Comment: Ok did some research. Strangely, a lot of the symptoms associated with the multi-lingual issues are similar here (blank page, no such field, undefined packages url).  The API explorer won't let me choose "System.rebuildmultilingualschema" because the wheel continues to spin. I also don't have access to use drush.

Comment: Try using rest api url to run the schema rebuild

Comment: What does your webserver log say? And what about the civicrm log file? Any indication of an error message? If nothing shows up you could possibly enable debug mode at: http://yoursite/civicrm/admin/settings/debug?reset=1

Comment: I updated the original post with all my errors, including my civicrm log file.

Comment: Kristine you will need to the rebuildschema as this a known bug as I mentioned in my answer. (Proof: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12636)

Comment: Or you will need to manually add this column through mysql

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: I did the sql query. Uploaded the file, SchemaStructure_5_4_alpha1.php just in case. Flushed the cache, no changes. I see that the console is not able to load the 'jquery.crmAjaxTable.js' still.

Comment: Can you check more errors in CiviCRM logs

Comment: I updated the log again from above, but it seems like the same log. It keeps looking for the JS files under undefinedpackages/jquery/. I don't think its the Resource URL issue though. I even copied the database to another server and the paths are correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81650/discussion-between-kristine-and-pradeep-nayak).