# DB error missing field in contribution reports after upgrade to 5.4.0 (Drupal)

Tags: error, contributions, database, reports, 5.0

After upgrade to 5.4.0 (from 4.7) I'm seeing fatal DB errors ("no such field") when refreshing Contribution Detail & Summary reports. Debug log shows:

> $Fatal Error Details = Array ( [callback] => Array ( [0] =>
>   CRM_Core_Error [1] => handle ) [code] => -19 [message] => DB Error: no
>   such field [mode] => 16 [debug_info] => SELECT
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_financial_type_id, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_financial_type_id,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_payment_instrument_id, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_payment_instrument_id,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contact_sort_name, '') as civicrm_contact_sort_name,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contact_id, '') as civicrm_contact_id,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_contribution_id, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_contribution_id,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_financial_type_id, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_financial_type_id,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_payment_instrument_id, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_payment_instrument_id,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_currency, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_currency,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_receive_date, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_receive_date,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_total_amount, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_total_amount,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_fee_amount, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_fee_amount,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_net_amount, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_net_amount,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_contribution_or_soft, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_contribution_or_soft,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_campaign_id, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_campaign_id,
>   ifnull(civicrm_value_gift_aid_declaration_custom_25, '') as
>   civicrm_value_gift_aid_declaration_custom_25,
>   ifnull(civicrm_value_gift_aid_declaration_custom_26, '') as
>   civicrm_value_gift_aid_declaration_custom_26,
>   ifnull(civicrm_value_gift_aid_declaration_custom_27, '') as
>   civicrm_value_gift_aid_declaration_custom_27 ,
>   sum(civicrm_contribution_total_amount) as sumcontribs, count(*) as ct
>   from civireport_contribution_detail_temp3 group by
>   civicrm_contribution_financial_type_id,
>   civicrm_contribution_payment_instrument_id [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown
>   column 'civicrm_contribution_total_amount' in 'field list'] [type] =>
>   DB_Error [user_info] => SELECT
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_financial_type_id, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_financial_type_id,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_payment_instrument_id, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_payment_instrument_id,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contact_sort_name, '') as civicrm_contact_sort_name,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contact_id, '') as civicrm_contact_id,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_contribution_id, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_contribution_id,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_financial_type_id, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_financial_type_id,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_payment_instrument_id, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_payment_instrument_id,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_currency, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_currency,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_receive_date, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_receive_date,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_total_amount, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_total_amount,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_fee_amount, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_fee_amount,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_net_amount, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_net_amount,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_contribution_or_soft, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_contribution_or_soft,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_campaign_id, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_campaign_id,
>   ifnull(civicrm_value_gift_aid_declaration_custom_25, '') as
>   civicrm_value_gift_aid_declaration_custom_25,
>   ifnull(civicrm_value_gift_aid_declaration_custom_26, '') as
>   civicrm_value_gift_aid_declaration_custom_26,
>   ifnull(civicrm_value_gift_aid_declaration_custom_27, '') as
>   civicrm_value_gift_aid_declaration_custom_27 ,
>   sum(civicrm_contribution_total_amount) as sumcontribs, count(*) as ct
>   from civireport_contribution_detail_temp3 group by
>   civicrm_contribution_financial_type_id,
>   civicrm_contribution_payment_instrument_id [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown
>   column 'civicrm_contribution_total_amount' in 'field list']
>   [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such field" code=-19
>   mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="SELECT
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_financial_type_id, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_financial_type_id,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_payment_instrument_id, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_payment_instrument_id,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contact_sort_name, '') as civicrm_contact_sort_name,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contact_id, '') as civicrm_contact_id,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_contribution_id, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_contribution_id,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_financial_type_id, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_financial_type_id,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_payment_instrument_id, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_payment_instrument_id,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_currency, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_currency,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_receive_date, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_receive_date,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_total_amount, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_total_amount,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_fee_amount, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_fee_amount,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_net_amount, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_net_amount,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_contribution_or_soft, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_contribution_or_soft,
>   ifnull(civicrm_contribution_campaign_id, '') as
>   civicrm_contribution_campaign_id,
>   ifnull(civicrm_value_gift_aid_declaration_custom_25, '') as
>   civicrm_value_gift_aid_declaration_custom_25,
>   ifnull(civicrm_value_gift_aid_declaration_custom_26, '') as
>   civicrm_value_gift_aid_declaration_custom_26,
>   ifnull(civicrm_value_gift_aid_declaration_custom_27, '') as
>   civicrm_value_gift_aid_declaration_custom_27 ,
>   sum(civicrm_contribution_total_amount) as sumcontribs, count(*) as ct
>   from civireport_contribution_detail_temp3 group by
>   civicrm_contribution_financial_type_id,
>   civicrm_contribution_payment_instrument_id [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown
>   column 'civicrm_contribution_total_amount' in 'field list']"] )

Key issue seems to be that civicrm_contribution_total_amount is not included in temp table civireport_contribution_detail_temp3

Checked on a 5.0 demo site listed on civicrm.org (https://drupal.demo.civicrmfr.org/civicrm/report/list?compid=2&reset=1 - the only one running 5.x) and get the same error.

Any help gratefully received...

Answer (score 1):

For some reason i am getting different no such field error i.e for contact.birth_date. I have locked the issue for this error at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/325 and submitted PR at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12660 .

I also logged issue for your bug at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/326  which happens when we enable Section header under sorting tab.

To fix this temporary until Core team have PR for it, i would suggest you to turn off section header.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Interesting. I could replicate this on a French language 5.0 version on civicrm.org

Comment: On French site the error is for 'contact.birth_date' which i have fixed it in my PR. I could replicate the error you getting now. I have updated my answer

Comment: Interesting. I could replicate this on a French language 5.3.1 version on civicrm.org. (as above), by logging in (demo/demo) -> choose CiviCRM -> choose "Rapport des contributions" -> Choose "Contribution details" then "Rafraichir le resultats"... Gives: DB Error. Turning off Section Header had not impact. Still errored.

Comment: Can you turn off 'Age' and 'Sexe' field under columns and try doing a search without section header?

Comment: I've turned off all optional columns and section header, but still get the error.

Comment: I am not sure how you doing this. I turned off the section header from sorting tab and 'Age' and 'Sexe' field under columns tab it worked for me in french site. So can you be specific with 'I've turned off all optional columns and section header'?

Comment: Sorry, I had tried turning off all columns in my demo system, not French system. On French demo system turning off Sexe cures error as you say. However, I am running 5.4.0, not 5.3.1 as on French system, so maybe another problem been introduced?

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: Probably worth rebuilding Multi-lingual schema since there were lot of issues for multi-lingual site after upgrade https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/25890/155

Comment: Pradeep, is there an easier/better way than comments to send an error log?

Comment: I have added my email id on my profile. You can send me there.