# how to troubleshoot template/ajax/caching/otherweirdness issue re: multilingual upgrade

Tags: ajax, i18n, multilingual

Thanks for the help in solving the problem!  Nice to have all the ajax working properly again.

Regarding the title of the question.... It seems like there's a (large?) gap between the errors I encountered and the solution for them.  I'm wondering what I could have done to troubleshoot more...? maybe if I had gone to a non-english page I would have encountered different errors...?  Is there anything that can be recommended regarding how I could've troubleshooted this more effectively?  This issue seems completely mysterious to me, so while "go ask the friendly people online" can yield easy solutions sometimes as it did this time, I'd like to learn something a little deeper here if possible :)

---

After updating to 5.4.1 Contact pages are behaving oddly...

- Activities don't show up at all until a filter is toggled (for example, there are 10 activities it says, but it displays none of them, but then changing the filters to exclude any type of activity will cause all 10 of the activities to appear).
- Relationships don't show up at all (and they don't have any ajaxy toggle thing to magically make them appear).

In the browser's debugging console I see

- `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`
- `Refused to execute script from 'http://ourwebsite.org/civicrm/contact/undefinedjs/jquery/jquery.crmAjaxTable.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

When Civi cache is flushed at /civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend a fatal error occurs followed by a backtrace.  They mention 'ajax' a number of times (and that's all that stands out to me as meaningful.  it says "DB Error: No such field" too, but I have no idea what field doesn't exist so maybe these errors are unrelated?)...

```
ID         :  6869
Date       :  28/Aug 19:48
Type       :  civicrm
Severity   :  debug
Message    :
              $Fatal Error Details = array(3) {
                ["message"]=>
                string(23) "DB Error: no such field"
                ["code"]=>
                NULL
                ["exception"]=>
                object(CiviCRM_API3_Exception)#181 (8) {
                  ["extraParams":"CiviCRM_API3_Exception":private]=>
                  array(4) {
                    ["error_code"]=>
                    string(13) "no such field"
                    ["tip"]=>
                    string(62) "add debug=1 to your API call to have more info about the error"
                    ["is_error"]=>
                    int(1)
                    ["error_message"]=>
                    string(23) "DB Error: no such field"
                  }
                  ["message":protected]=>
                  string(23) "DB Error: no such field"
                  ["string":"Exception":private]=>
                  string(0) ""
                  ["code":protected]=>
                  int(0)
                  ["file":protected]=>
                  string(65)
              "/home/milk/dev_html/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php"
                  ["line":protected]=>
                  int(45)
                  ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
                  array(10) {
                    [0]=>
                    array(4) {
                      ["file"]=>
                      string(78)
              "/home/milk/dev_html/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php"
                      ["line"]=>
                      int(3340)
                      ["function"]=>
                      string(12) "civicrm_api3"
                      ["args"]=>
                      array(3) {
                        [0]=>
                        &string(8) "uf_group"
                        [1]=>
                        &string(3) "get"
                        [2]=>
                        &array(2) {
                          ["name"]=>
                          array(1) {
                            ["IN"]=>
                            array(3) {
                              [0]=>
                              string(14) "new_individual"
                              [1]=>
                              string(16) "new_organization"
                              [2]=>
                              string(13) "new_household"
                            }
                          }
                          ["is_active"]=>
                          int(1)
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    [1]=>
                    array(6) {
                      ["file"]=>
                      string(76)
              "/home/milk/dev_html/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Resources.php"
                      ["line"]=>
                      int(689)
                      ["function"]=>
                      string(14) "getCreateLinks"
                      ["class"]=>
                      string(20) "CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup"
                      ["type"]=>
                      string(2) "::"
                      ["args"]=>
                      array(0) {
                      }
                    }
                    [2]=>
                    array(4) {
                      ["function"]=>
                      string(20) "outputLocalizationJS"
                      ["class"]=>
                      string(18) "CRM_Core_Resources"
                      ["type"]=>
                      string(2) "::"
                      ["args"]=>
                      array(0) {
                      }
                    }
                    [3]=>
                    array(4) {
                      ["file"]=>
                      string(73)
              "/home/milk/dev_html/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php"
                      ["line"]=>
                      int(275)
                      ["function"]=>
                      string(14) "call_user_func"
                      ["args"]=>
                      array(1) {
                        [0]=>
                        &array(2) {
                          [0]=>
                          string(18) "CRM_Core_Resources"
                          [1]=>
                          string(20) "outputLocalizationJS"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    [4]=>
                    array(6) {
                      ["file"]=>
                      string(73)
              "/home/milk/dev_html/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php"
                      ["line"]=>
                      int(84)
                      ["function"]=>
                      string(7) "runItem"
                      ["class"]=>
                      string(15) "CRM_Core_Invoke"
                      ["type"]=>
                      string(2) "::"
                      ["args"]=>
                      array(1) {
                        [0]=>
                        &array(12) {
                          ["id"]=>
                          string(3) "149"
                          ["domain_id"]=>
                          string(1) "1"
                          ["path"]=>
                          string(20) "civicrm/ajax/l10n-js"
                          ["access_callback"]=>
                          string(1) "1"
                          ["access_arguments"]=>
                          array(2) {
                            [0]=>
                            array(1) {
                              [0]=>
                              string(14) "access CiviCRM"
                            }
                            [1]=>
                            string(3) "and"
                          }
                          ["page_callback"]=>
                          array(2) {
                            [0]=>
                            string(18) "CRM_Core_Resources"
                            [1]=>
                            string(20) "outputLocalizationJS"
                          }
                          ["breadcrumb"]=>
                          array(1) {
                            [0]=>
                            array(2) {
                              ["title"]=>
                              string(7) "CiviCRM"
                              ["url"]=>
                              string(16) "/civicrm?reset=1"
                            }
                          }
                          ["is_ssl"]=>
                          string(1) "0"
                          ["weight"]=>
                          string(1) "1"
                          ["type"]=>
                          string(1) "1"
                          ["page_type"]=>
                          string(1) "0"
                          ["page_arguments"]=>
                          bool(false)
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    [5]=>
                    array(6) {
                      ["file"]=>
                      string(73)
              "/home/milk/dev_html/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php"
                      ["line"]=>
                      int(52)
                      ["function"]=>
                      string(7) "_invoke"
                      ["class"]=>
                      string(15) "CRM_Core_Invoke"
                      ["type"]=>
                      string(2) "::"
                      ["args"]=>
                      array(1) {
                        [0]=>
                        &array(4) {
                          [0]=>
                          string(7) "civicrm"
                          [1]=>
                          string(4) "ajax"
                          [2]=>
                          string(7) "l10n-js"
                          [3]=>
                          string(5) "en_US"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    [6]=>
                    array(6) {
                      ["file"]=>
                      string(75)
              "/home/milk/dev_html/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module"
                      ["line"]=>
                      int(445)
                      ["function"]=>
                      string(6) "invoke"
                      ["class"]=>
                      string(15) "CRM_Core_Invoke"
                      ["type"]=>
                      string(2) "::"
                      ["args"]=>
                      array(1) {
                        [0]=>
                        &array(4) {
                          [0]=>
                          string(7) "civicrm"
                          [1]=>
                          string(4) "ajax"
                          [2]=>
                          string(7) "l10n-js"
                          [3]=>
                          string(5) "en_US"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    [7]=>
                    array(2) {
                      ["function"]=>
                      string(14) "civicrm_invoke"
                      ["args"]=>
                      array(3) {
                        [0]=>
                        &string(4) "ajax"
                        [1]=>
                        &string(7) "l10n-js"
                        [2]=>
                        &string(5) "en_US"
                      }
                    }
                    [8]=>
                    array(4) {
                      ["file"]=>
                      string(45) "/home/milk/dev_html/docroot/includes/menu.inc"
                      ["line"]=>
                      int(527)
                      ["function"]=>
                      string(20) "call_user_func_array"
                      ["args"]=>
                      array(2) {
                        [0]=>
                        &string(14) "civicrm_invoke"
                        [1]=>
                        &array(3) {
                          [0]=>
                          string(4) "ajax"
                          [1]=>
                          string(7) "l10n-js"
                          [2]=>
                          string(5) "en_US"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    [9]=>
                    array(4) {
                      ["file"]=>
                      string(37) "/home/milk/dev_html/docroot/index.php"
                      ["line"]=>
                      int(21)
                      ["function"]=>
                      string(27) "menu_execute_active_handler"
                      ["args"]=>
                      array(0) {
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  ["previous":"Exception":private]=>
                  NULL
                }
              }
```

and the backtrace that followed:

```
ID         :  6870                                                                              
Date       :  28/Aug 19:48                                                                      
Type       :  civicrm                                                                           
Severity   :  debug                                                                             
Message    :  $backTrace = #0                                                                   
              /home/milk/dev_html/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(459):    
              CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)                                      
              #1 /home/milk/dev_html/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(55): 
              CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CiviCRM_API3_Exception))          
              #2                                                                                
              /home/milk/dev_html/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(445): 
              CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))                                                
              #3 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("ajax", "l10n-js", "en_US")              
              #4 /home/milk/dev_html/docroot/includes/menu.inc(527):                            
              call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:3))                                 
              #5 /home/milk/dev_html/docroot/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()       
              #6 {main}
```

I don't know if those Drupal log entries are related to this problem, but I do suspect the javascript errors are...

Could the problem lie in jquery.crmAjaxTable.js?  Doing `chmod +x jquery.crmAjaxTable.js` doesn't solve that.

But now after clearing the cache again have a couple more js errors, in addition to the two above are these:

- `Error: CRM.url called before initialization
  CRM.console @ Common.js?pe6q8l:1605
  CRM.url @ crm.ajax.js?pe6q8l:19
  crmFormInline @ Summary.js?pe6q8l:23
  (anonymous) @ Summary.js?pe6q8l:201
  dispatch @ jquery.min.js?pe6q8l:3
  r.handle @ jquery.min.js?pe6q8l:3`
- `crm.ajax.js?pe6q8l:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'back' of undefined
  at Object.CRM.url (crm.ajax.js?pe6q8l:26)
  at crmFormInline (Summary.js?pe6q8l:23)
  at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (Summary.js?pe6q8l:201)
  at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js?pe6q8l:3)
  at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js?pe6q8l:3)
  CRM.url @ crm.ajax.js?pe6q8l:26
  crmFormInline @ Summary.js?pe6q8l:23
  (anonymous) @ Summary.js?pe6q8l:201
  dispatch @ jquery.min.js?pe6q8l:3
  r.handle @ jquery.min.js?pe6q8l:3`

Comment: It looks like the upgrade script did not run successfully - did it give any errors? Do you have a multilingual site? Is audit logging turned on?

Comment: I don't recall any errors from the upgrade script.  The site is multilingual (Drupal+i18n).  What do you mean by "audit" logging?

Comment: well what we normally call logging - creates log tables. Try running the api

System.rebuildmultilingualschema

Comment: Check the answers to this issue. Sounds similar https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/25888/4519

Comment: yes! `cv api System.rebuildmultilingualschema` and cache flush and it's now working properly.  Thanks @user4278 and @ericG!

Comment: Post that as the answer. Glad it worked

Answer (score 0):

What stands out to me in your error report is the word "undefined" in `http://ourwebsite.org/civicrm/contact/`**undefined**`js/jquery/jquery.crmAjaxTable.js`. I think your resource url setting may have been messed up. Check **Administer -> System Settings -> Resource URLs**.

Comment: The CiviCRM Resource URL is `[civicrm.root]/`.

Comment: I don't know what that token is for though.  The CIviCRM module is located in sites/all/modules/civicrm... is that what that token is referring to?  I assume it's not referring to the Drupal root...?  I'm looking into replacing that token with a hardcoded value to see if that makes a difference...

Comment: I followed the check at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/resource-urls/ (finding the civicrm.css file when viewing the source and then loading it in the browser, the browser can load it)... so seemingly it's *not* a problem in the Resource Urls...?

Comment: But yeah, **undefined** stands out, right?  More undefined in here: `<div class="menu-item"><span>Customize Data and Screens</span><img class="menu-item-arrow" src="undefinedpackages/jquery/css/images/arrow.png" style="top: 4px;"></div>`

Comment: Looks like for some reason `CRM.config.resourceBase` is undefined.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `CRM.config.resourceBase`...

Comment: And that comes from `userFrameworkResourceURL` setting.

Comment: Did you try the hardcoded value?

Comment: I did, the full url `http...modules/civicrm`, cleaned cache, still didn't work.  Then I tried on the cache page the Reset Paths button, and it didn't work either, just replaced the hardcoded value with the original token.